# How to enable ckeditor in the emails templates at admin/config/people/accounts?

Tags: emails, wysiwyg

Just that.

I need to enable ckeditor to write the text body for the **welcome e-mail message** at `admin/config/people/accounts`

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know how to do it; but I doubt even after achieving this, the mails would be sent as plain text, which is the default format of the mails sent from a Drupal site. I suggest you to look for some other menthod for formatting(using html in) emails

Comment: Using html is what I do, but my client want to be able to periodically change these emails and he has no html knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) for [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/361112);
2. Add below code to your module;
3. **replace all** MODULENAME in code to your module name;
4. clear cache;
5. refresh /admin/config/people/accounts page

For all textarea fields there's text selector appear - you should select format, where ckeditor attached:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for user settings page.
 */
function MODULENAME_form_user_admin_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  _MODULENAME_form_user_admin_settings_elements($form);
}

/**
 * Scan through elements.
 */
function _MODULENAME_form_user_admin_settings_elements(&$elements) {
  // Recurse through all children.
  foreach (element_children($elements) as $key) {
    if (isset($elements[$key]) && $elements[$key]) {
      if (isset($elements[$key]['#type']) && ($elements[$key]['#type'] == 'textarea')) {
        $elements[$key]['#type'] = 'text_format'; 
      }
      else {
        _MODULENAME_form_user_admin_settings_elements($elements[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- be warn, that placeholders signs [bla-bla:something] can be replaced by unicode symbols (&XXXX;), check before to show your client.
- if you want add text format only for certain textarea use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) function for seeking that element and setting next code `$elements[CERTAIN_ARRAY_PATH2ELEMENT]['#type'] = 'text_format';` without scanning through all elements.

Comment: Thanks Nikit for your answer But I got an error when I save the configuration of admin page, the body part of the template will be blank.I done this in the default user email template.And I am not using any module for mail templates. Actually my task is to send HTML in the email i.e. email body with header and footer tag.
Can you please suggest any solution. Pallavi

Comment: 2Pallavi: what error it's show?

Comment: I have the same problem, I face blank page after saving content. The error message is " Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1572

Comment: I have checked again this code, and it's successfully work on clean Drupal with ckeditor and custom module. Looks like troubles came from another thing, I need to debug for recognizing bug...

Answer (score 1):

In my answer I'm only going to focus on **Welcome (no approval required)** email body field.

- First make sure to install [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module and its dependencies
- Create **Full HTML** format if its not being created yet `admin/config/content/formats`
- Implement the following code in a module and replace `mymodule` with your own module name

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_user_admin_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // alter type textarea to text_format  
  $form['email_no_approval_required']['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body']['#type'] = 'text_format';

  // alter default format to full_html (you need to create this format before you assign it)
  $form['email_no_approval_required']['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body']['#format'] = 'full_html';

  // add validation function to alter field value before submit (before saving it to variable tables)
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_system_settings_form_validate';
}


function mymodule_system_settings_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // get submitted value      
  $html = $form_state['values']['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body'];

  // set value of the submitted value
  form_set_value($form['email_no_approval_required']['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body'], $html['value'], $form_state);
}
```

The reason I'm using validate function is to alter field value before submitting value and store it into `variable` table. Without altering the value Drupal will store value as **array (value, format)** and users will start getting `Array` as text instead of the actual text that you need them to see.

Answer (score 0):

if the field format is choosen as long text

in the

```
  admin/config/people/accounts/
```

click on modify then select

```
 treatment: filter text
```